# Vue 3 Typescript define unknown array of object

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I'm using vue 3 with quasar and I would to make a wrapper for q-table but how can I define rows without using any[].

It works like this but then whenever I use this component I'll have to convert my object to unknown. Is there any better way? Or I should just turn off "no-explicit-any" and use any[]?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <q-table
      :rows="rows"
      :columns="columns"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { computed } from 'vue';
import { QTableProps } from 'node_modules/quasar/dist/types/index';

interface Props {
  columns?: QTableProps['columns'];
  rows?: unknown[];
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  rows: undefined
});

const rows = computed(() => props.rows)
const columns = computed(() => props.columns)


</script>
```

Comment: If you don't care about the type of rows just use any[]. It's fine. If you want the IDE checks the type of rows then define an explicit type for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTable.rows` expects an array of objects, containing string keys and string/number values.

So `rows` should be typed as:

```js
interface Props {
  columns?: QTableProps['columns'];
  rows?: Record<string, string | number>[]; 
}
```

*Side notes:*

- Specifying `undefined` as a default value is effectively the same as not specifying a default at all. You can remove the `withDefaults()` in your example.
- The computed props that just return the original props have no useful effect. You could remove these computed props, and just use `props.rows` and `props.columns` directly.